# C# Method overloading is calling the wrong method when using string args

Tags: c#, overloading, args

I'm trying to make a log plugin for myself and I want to have a method where I overload it with different parameters. 
The key is, it needs to be possible to add multiple strings, which I will print on different lines. I like the idea of using `params`, that way I don't need to add `string[] { strings here }` everytime.

The issue I currently have is that the `Log.L()` method will not trigger the first, but the second method, which kinda makes sense.

How can I solve this issue, while keeping the `params`?

```
Log.L("line1", "line2", "line3");

public static class Log
{
   public static void L(params string[] message)
   {
       Write(LogType.Log, message);
   }   

   public static void L(string location, params string[] message)
   {
       Write(LogType.Log, message, false, location);
   }
}
```

Comment: Just name the methods differently.  No one says you *have* to use method overloading; it's mostly for convenience.

Comment: I agree, but it looks so much better with overloading. Before applying this, i wanna see other solutions pop-up ^^

Comment: By the way...`L` is not a great method name anyway.  Something more descriptive would be much better.

Comment: Well I've got the idea from Android Studio. They use L for logging, D for debugging, etc. I like the idea though. All it needs is some good documentation, right? :D

Comment: `params` is the feature of having multiple parameters wrapped into an array for you, not `args`.

Comment: That was a typo, thanks for noticing!

Comment: if you really want you can call the first one like this L(message: new [] { "YTF would you do this"});

Comment: Rory's suggestion is the right one here. There is no way to force the compiler to use the other method. It will always select "public static void L(string location, params string[] message)" because it is the most specific. So, you need to disambiguate. You can use a different type (like, is Location really an enum? a Path?), a different method name, or just keep one method. But honestly, I don't get why params is useful here anyways. StringBuilder is easy enough to use, is lightweight, and it's clear what is happening.

Comment: @ChiralMichael I'll eventually go with using different method names. The location will always be a string path name. I could perhaps turn this into a Directory object, but I prefer to have a static method without a lot of pre-instantiating. The reason why I want to use params over string array or stringbuilder, is having extra code for calling the method. The string array would still be relatively simple, but I just want to quickly give in my parameters, debug the tool and move on to the next part

Comment: @rory.ap I'm also going with clearer method names ;)

Answer (score 0):

It will always assume that the first string is `location` so, just use the second overload:

```
public static void L(string location, params string[] message)
   {
       Write(LogType.Log, message, false, location);
   }
```

you can simply pass null or empty string when location is not available and deal with it in the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two classes and use them to differentiate between the two overloads. You can even go so far as having one class inherit from the other if you want.

```
public class LoginWithMessages {
    public string[] Messages {get; set;}
}

public class LoginWithLocation : LoginWithMessages {
    public string Location {get; set;}
}
```

Then your method signatures will be:

```
public static void L(LoginWithMessages loginMessage)

public static void L(LoginWithLocation loginLocation)
```